My laptop don't turn on
Today I installed Ubuntu after the Windows and the laptop do not turn on.
Under Windows, I did not have this problem.
A half years before I had Debian on this same laptop and this turned on with a big delay...

If it does not turn on at all, it is a hardware issue. Or does it get stuck at the UEFI screen or the GRUB screen?

What version of Ubuntu did you install? Add this info and the laptop hardware details to the question with edit.
